# object, Object instead of correct data from object VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I pass the following props in my month component

```js
 props: {
          actionEvents: this.selectedEvent && this.selectedEvent.calendar && this.selectedEvent.id || this.selectedEvent
        }
```

In my ChangeCalendar component I'm trying to update the api by doing the following:

```js
        ? this.$api.calendar.update(
          this.actionEvents && this.actionEvents.id && this.actionEvents.calendar || this.actionEvents,
           data
```

I need both Id and calendar for the route to update but the output I get is:
**"/calendars/f2User-51-5594439/events/[object Object]"**. I would expect object Object to return the calendar value (which is a string and is something like: f2User-51-actions).

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? I dont understand why Id does return the expected value but calendar doesn't

When I look into the data and props of my components:

[image: hoi]

Comment: The question lacks the context and debugging info. It's unclear what all mentioned data is. "I would expect object Object to return the calendar value (which is a string and is something like: f2User-51-actions)" - you probably know that but others don't. You could debug what [object Object] value actually is in the place where it's used. The code overuse short circuit operators, it's unnecessary that they work according to your expectations. if actionEvents is an obj but id or calendar are falsy for some reason we cannot know, it will still be used, which is probably the case here

Comment: Looks like the default “toString” of an object.